# How to insert and select encrypted column from SQL into asp.net core

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, encryption, azure-keyvault

I am using SQL as database. Encrypt some column of table using Azure Key Vault. Now I want to insert and select data from asp.net core.
I also add 'Column Encryption Setting=Enabled' in my connection string.

But I am getting following error while trying to insert data from asp.net core.

"The data types nvarchar(600) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto2', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'DB') and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator."

Here is code for reference

```
var s = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionString").GetSection("_ConnectionString").Value;
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(s))
{
 using (var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
 {
 command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 command.CommandText = "_Insert_Update_Customer_Bank_Details";
 sqlConnection.Open();
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.Customer_Bank_Detail_Id));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cust_contact_id", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.Cust_Contact_Id));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Customer_Id", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.Customer_Id));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@User_Id", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.UserId));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name_On_Account", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.Name_On_Account));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Account_Number", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.Account_Number));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Bank_Name", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.Bank_Name));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Bank_Routing_Number", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.Bank_Routing_Number));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Bank_Account_Type", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.BankAccountType));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Bank_Reg_Mobile", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.Bank_Regestered_Mobile));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Bank_Reg_Email", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.Bank_Regestered_Email));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Login_User_Id", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.Created_By));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mode", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.Mode));
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Federal_tax_id", bank_Account_Customer_Entity.FTax));
//add fedral tax
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MESSAGE_ID", SqlDbType.Int));
command.Parameters["@MESSAGE_ID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MESSAGE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5000));
command.Parameters["@MESSAGE"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Primary_Out_Id", SqlDbType.BigInt));
command.Parameters["@Primary_Out_Id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Here is the database design for my table.
I want 4 columns to get encrypted, they are: `Name_On_Account`, `Account_Number`, `Bank_Name`, `Bank_Routing_Number`.

Table design:

[image: table design]

Comment: Can you please post the table definition as well?

Comment: The code seams correct. Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/always-encrypted-azure-key-vault-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#modify-your-connection-string-to-enable-always-encrypted. Just from the error message, it seams that the the data is out of table data type length.

Comment: @KalyanChanumolu-MSFT@Leon Yue I am added table design in my question. Thank you for your response